# spring configuration files relationship?

Tags: java, spring, java-ee-6, spring-ioc

I am using spring3.x. i have below configuration files in my application.

```
applicationContext.xml
spring-ws-servlet.xml
```

### web.xml

```
   <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:config/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


<servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:config/spring-ws-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

My question is what kind of beans do we need to keep in `applicationContext.xml` and what kind of beans do we need to keep in `spring-ws-servlet.xml` ? why do we need both? Shall i keep everything in `applicationContext.xml` and delete `spring-ws-servlet.xml` ?

If i have both then should i import one in another ? Please help  me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:config/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

You must have a listener defined as this:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This `ContextLoaderListener` listener is responsible for starting and stopping the Spring `root ApplicationContext` interface, which loads the beans defined in `applicationContext.xml`. It finds the configurations to be used  by looking at the `<context-param>` tag for `contextConfigLocation`.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:config/spring-ws-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
</servlet>
```

The `ApplicationContext` created by `DispatcherServlet` is a child of the `root ApplicationContext` interface. **Typically, Spring MVC-specific components
are initialized in the ApplicationContext interface of DispatcherServlet, while
the rest are loaded by `ContextLoaderListener`**.

The beans in a `child ApplicationContext` (such as those created by DispatcherServlet) can refer to beans of its parent ApplicationContext (such as those created by ContextLoaderListener). However, the `parent ApplicationContext` cannot refer to beans of the `child ApplicationContext`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of contexts we are dealing with:

**1:** root context (parent context. Typically include all jdbc(ORM, Hibernate) initialisation and other spring security related configuration)

**2:** individual servlet context (child context.Typically Dispatcher Servlet Context and initialise all beans related to spring-mvc (controllers , URL Mapping etc)).

Here is an example of web.xml which includes multiple application context file

> http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
>
> ```
> <display-name>Spring Web Application example</display-name>
>
> <!-- Configurations for the root application context (parent context) -->
> <listener>
>     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
> </listener>
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
>     <param-value>
>         /WEB-INF/spring/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xml <!-- JDBC related context -->
>         /WEB-INF/spring/security/spring-security-context.xml <!-- Spring Security related context -->
>     </param-value>
> </context-param>
>
> <!-- Configurations for the DispatcherServlet application context (child context) -->
> <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
>     <init-param>
>         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
>         <param-value>
>             /WEB-INF/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-servlet.xml
>         </param-value>
>     </init-param>
> </servlet>
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```